# List of useful Android libraries for android development and applications

Tags: android

Android is not only a framework/SDK but also a big constellation of libraries and tools that can be more or less useful when developping Android apps. 
I am always looking for better tools to help me improve my coding or improve my apps design so, If you don't mind sharing your discoveries, I'll add them to my short list :

[android-annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) : Helps you reduce the amount of code in your android classes by using annotations to generate usual code for you.

[Spring android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android)

[Sensor emulator](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/23) : Simulates accelerometer, compass, and orientation sensors, as well as a temperature sensor

[Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/) : Jar that can be used to display phone screen on a desktop/laptop. Very handy for presentations for instance.

[SQLITE Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) Browse your exported database from Eclipse on your desktop, execute some requests or update manually some values. No update since 2009 but still handy.

If you think any tool you know is better (more options, works better/quicker) or could be added here don't hesitate to particpate.
I would have be thrilled to find such a list when I started Android, so I hope It will help some people...

Comment: Is this intended as a wiki? Wont this be flagged as not constructive?

Comment: Yes it is non-constructive. Besides, why would you add such overhead as introspection and reflection when your end-result will run on limited hardware.

Comment: This is not intended as a wiki as I am a android developer, a trainer on the subject and publisher of a few apps. So I'm always looking for new tools to help me improve my developments. However, I think sharing these tools is useful for everyone here.

Comment: I guess my question is not written properly and sounds more like a wiki than a helper for me and others...

Comment: You could also find a lot of useful libraries here: http://android-arsenal.com

Answer (score 1):

[ORM lite](http://ormlite.com/): lightweight Object Relational Mapping framework for persisting java objects to DB's (free)
[Active Android](https://www.activeandroid.com/): ORM framework like ORM lite, a bit smaller, but requires a license